# Custom Gradle Java plugin crashes in v5.2.1, but worked in v4.7?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

My plugin worked in Gradle v4.7, but is now crashing v5.2.1. I know that's a HUGE version jump.

I wrote a custom Gradle java plugin, and this the plugin implementation class. I put a breakpoint in the `task.setProject(project)` call, but it never gets there.

```
package com.zift.utilities;

import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

public class ZiftVersionPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("manageVersion", ZiftVersion.class, (task) -> {
            // Added breakpoint here, but it's never reached!
            task.setProject(project);
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: (added simplified plugin code below)

Here's the simplified class that implements the `manageVersion` task. All the `import` statements will probably be unnecessary with this code.

```
package com.zift.utilities;

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Input;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.options.Option;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

public class ZiftVersion extends DefaultTask {
    @Input private Project project;
    private String projectDir=null;
    private String propFileFullPath=null;
    private String sourceBranch=null;
    private String destinationBranch="staging";

    String getPropFile() { return propFileFullPath; }
    void setPropFile(String fn) { this.propFileFullPath = fn; }

    public Project getProject() { return project; }
    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
        this.projectDir = this.project.getRootDir().toString();
    }

    // The void set*() functions have to immediately follow their corresponding
    // @Option() so they can take arguments in the command line, e.g.,
    // $ ./gradlew manageVersion \
    //             --srcBranch=bugfix/devops-507-semver --dstBranch=master
    @Option(option = "srcBranch", description = "Source branch of the pull request")
    public void setSrcBranch(String s) { this.sourceBranch = s; }
    public String getSrcBranch() { return sourceBranch; }

    @Option(option = "dstBranch", description = "Destination branch of the pull request")
    public void setDstBranch(String d) { this.destinationBranch = d; }
    public String getDstBranch() { return destinationBranch; }

    @TaskAction
    void manageProjectVersion() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Here's my project's `build.gradle` file to build the plugin

```
plugins {
  id 'idea'
  id 'java'
  id 'maven'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}

group=project.groupId
version = '666.666.666'

dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'artifactId': 'zift-version-plugin',
               'groupId': 'com.zift.utilities',
               'version': project.version
  }
  baseName artifactId
  doLast {
    println "artifactId: $project.artifactId\ngroupId: $project.groupId\nversion: $version"
  }
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        simplePlugin {
            id = 'com.zift.utilities.zift-version-plugin'
            implementationClass = 'com.zift.utilities.ZiftVersionPlugin'
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I use it, from another Gradle project that uses the plugin

```
$ ./gradlew manageVersion --srcBranch=feature/devops-507-semver-support --dstBranch=master
> Task :manageVersion
Hello world!
```

Here's the [exception](https://scans.gradle.com/s/22wivonbntzle/failure?openFailures=WzBd&openStackTraces=WzNd#top=0), which looks like it occurred during the `create()` function call.

```
Caused by org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':manageVersion'
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException:  (No message provided)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyUtils.visitProperties(TaskPropertyUtils.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.PropertyAssociationTaskFactory.create(PropertyAssociationTaskFactory.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:46)
...
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:359)
at com.zift.utilities.ZiftVersionPlugin.apply(ZiftVersionPlugin.java:8)
```

Any clues?

Comment: Since you use a debugger, you should set a breakpoint in `TaskPropertyUtils.visitProperties()` and investigate what value is null when the exception happens.

Comment: @tkruse, i put a breakpoint there and it seems to error out in this loop. I get lost in the Java code after that.         

`for (Object path : ((TaskDestroyablesInternal) task.getDestroyables()).getRegisteredPaths()) {
            visitor.visitDestroyableProperty(new DefaultTaskDestroyablePropertySpec("$" + ++destroyableCount, path));
        }`

Comment: Not sure if anyone else can help debugging without the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tkruse, I added a simplified "Hello world" version of the task code.

Comment: when trying your plugin code using Gradle v4.7 I got compilation error at `task.setProject(project);` : there is no setter for `project` property on `AbstractTask` (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.7.0/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/AbstractTask.java ) :  how could you make this plugin work in Gradle 4.7 ?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I took out too much crap. I edited the OP and I actually was able to build this code in 4.7 anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Idiocy is the cause, my idiocy particularly.

I compiled my plugin with Gradle wrapper from v4.x, so when a project built with v5.x or above uses it, the plugin crashes.

Solution is to upgrade my plugin's wrapper to Gradle v6.0, build and publish a new version, and have projects use the new version. No more crashes.