# What should be the variable type for this Java method?

Tags: java, gradle-plugin

This is related to [Custom Gradle Java plugin crashes in v5.2.1, but worked in v4.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60499809/custom-gradle-java-plugin-crashes-in-v5-2-1-but-worked-in-v4-7). Caveat - I'm not a Java programmer.

I have this code to implement a Plugin, and it's crashing (per other post).

```
package com.zift.utilities;

import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

public class ZiftVersionPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("manageVersion", ZiftVersion.class, (task) -> {
            // Added breakpoint here, but it's never reached!
            task.setProject(project);
        });
    }
}
```

I want to separate this line into 2 lines so I can debug better in IntelliJ. So from

```
project.getTasks().create(...)
```

...to

```
Vartype??? tasks = project.getTasks()
tasks.create(...)
```

What should `Vartype` be for the `project.getTasks()` call? I just wanna set a breakpoint on both lines to see where it's crashing. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getTasks--

Comment: If you use an IDE (for example IntelliJ) you can hold down CTRL and hover on the method to see the return type of it.

Comment: What I often do is simply put a type I know is wrong, say, `int`, and let the IDE suggest a fix to change it to the correct type. Ctrl-1 does this in Eclipse. I assume there's something similar in IntelliJ. This is also convenient when the type name is long and onerous to have to type in full.

Answer (score 0):

It's `org.gradle.api.taasks.TaskContainer`. So the code looks like

```
package com.zift.utilities;

import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer;

public class ZiftVersionPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        TaskContainer taskContainer = project.getTasks();
        taskContainer.create("manageVersion", ZiftVersion.class, (task) -> {
            // Added breakpoint here, but it's never reached!
            task.setProject(project);
        });
    }
}
```